# Trying to replace HIVE string literal with variable in HQL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

Hi I have a simple create table statement...

```
set location_stage=${env:HDFS_STAGING_DIR};
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stage.test(
TEST_ID INT,
TEST_NAME STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION "${hivevar:location_stage}";
```

I don't need the 'hivevar:location_stage' - I just need the 'env:HDFS_STAGING_DIR'.  However, neither is working.  I have used both in the 'LOCATION' clause.  I run both with the command line

```
hive -f test_hive_variable.sql
```

But I get the following error...

```
FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: ${hivevar:location_stage%7D
```

The hive version is Hive 1.2.1000.2.4.2.0-258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stage.test(
TEST_ID INT,
TEST_NAME STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION "${HDFS_STAGING_DIR}";
```

And then to pass `HDFS_STAGING_DIR`, you can use:

```
hive -f test_hive_variable.hql --hivevar HDFS_STAGING_DIR="/user/hive/warehouse/staging_dir"
```

Comment: I owe you a beer sir

Comment: @Mike Can't say no to that. Cheers.